# How to point an ingress with 2 ELB and a single controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I've successfully installed a single ingress nginx controller that has an internal and an external ELB.
Now I want to point my ingress to the internal ELB but I cannot make it work.
I followed the documentation of the helm chart
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
and again with the controller everything worked but I can't find any docuentation on how to configure the ingress.
In the doc it just says By default, the ingress object will point to the external load balancer address, but if correctly configured, you can make use of the internal one if the URL you are looking up resolves to the internal load balancer's URL.

Please help. I really don't want to have 2 controllers.
Thanks